# Why does terminfo disagree with read?

Tags: terminfo

I'm using xterm. If I type `infocmp $TERM | grep end`, I see that `kend=\EOF`. However, if I type `read`, and then the End key, I see that the sequence `\E[F` is generated. This seems to be a problem with other keys, too.

Surely the values should be identical??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The terminal can be set on a special mode to send keystrokes from the keypad. You can set that mode by running `tput smkx` and unset it by `tput rmkx`.